# Use Windows Key in tmux

Tags: linux, command-line, tmux

I'm using a PC a lot where X is not running.

I want to use the left windows key instead of control-b as the escape character for tmux

How can I achieve this? Without xev, etc. I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent tool to `xev` for a virtual terminal on a GNU/Linux machine is the command `showkey`. Just start it and press some keys. It will dump key codes to stdout. Please read the man-page of showkey, for it contains important information about key codes under kernels newer than 2.4.x and how to configure your system to get correct dumps.

You can then use the key code (left win-key is usually 115) to set your preferences in your ~/.tmux.conf like so:

`set-option -g prefix <keycode>`

`unbind-key C-b`

`bind-key <keycode> send-prefix`

See the official tmux documentation for details: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1

Comment: On my system the windows key is 125, but I get a 'bad key' error when I use it with tmux?

Comment: I read up on this stuff and found a hint in `man keymaps`. Apparently the virtual terminal is not prepared to deal with Windows-keys, at least there is no mention how to map them. Sorry.